# I want to parse out a json with only the information that I want

Tags: python, pandas

Are there any tools for parsing a .json file format

Comment: Start by describing **in words** the steps you need to accomplish this task. After you have a clear idea of these steps, you can start to translate them into code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot selectively parse JSON. This makes no sense as how can yo tell where is the section you selectively demanding, without parsing whole file? That said, JSON have to be read usually as whole, however you can selectively **process** loaded JSON by own criteria. I'd sufficient to iterate over `activities` node, check value of `action_type` and act accordingly. You need to write that code yourself. There's no `makePortal()` magic in the language to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Load the full json data and filter it after loading

```
import json
data = json.load(open('data.json'))
activities = [act for act in data['activities'] if '_STAGE_CHANGE' in act['composite_id']]
```